# vagrant - .bashrc has correct exports, but variables aren't correct

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant, vagrantfile

I didn't write the vagrant file - it was made by a colleague of mine, and I'm not overly familiar with writing them, but based on what they look like, I can understand what it's doing to an extent. I'm running Windows and a precise32 virtualbox, and emulating some sort of Linux system.

Basically what's happening is the vagrant file executes bootstrap.sh, which contains the following line:

```
cat /vagrant/support/bash-template.dat >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

support/bash-template.dat contains

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

When I check .bashrc after ssh'ing into vagrant, it has this line at the bottom.

If I do

```
> echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I get

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

But if I do

```
>cd $JAVA_HOME
```

I get

```
: No file or directorya-7-openjdk-i386
```

What's going on here? It just mashes the latter half of the variable with the error message.

And the directory exists! If I go from root, I can do

```
~> cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

And it brings me to the java home place.
I can reexport variables in the shell, and they work, but it would be very helpful to be able to do it from .bashrc so I don't have to reexport all 15 variables every single time I log on.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This sounds like a windows CRLF problem. Open `.bashrc` in a text editor that will show you line endings and make sure that you have `\n` unix-style endings instead of Windows.

Comment: The fact that that error message is all confused like that is the clue. The `bash-template.dat` file has DOS newlines. Which bash, expecting Unix line endings, does not handle correctly. Convert the file to unix line endings and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dos2unix` util to fix your line ending mismatch.